# Start a VisualState transition from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visualstatemanager

In a user control (or whatever), we all know that the VisualStateManger can be used in code to start a transition, or animation, like so:

```
    if (target.IsLocked)
    {
      VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Locked", true);
    }
    else if (target.IsBroken)
    {
      VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Broken", true);
    }
    else
    {
      VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", true);
    }
```

However, there seems to be very little or no information about triggering these type of animations from XAML.  Could a DataTemplate or Trigger be defined that could provide behaviour equivalent to the code listed above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Interativity` from the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22829) i am sure you could do something like this.

**Edit:** It contains a [`GoToStateAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.gotostateaction%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) specifically for this.

There are other libraries like [Markup Programming](http://markupprogramming.codeplex.com/) which might be able to do something similar. It also demonstrates that you can do pretty much anything in XAML if you want to.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Blend is for WPF

Comment: The markup programming seems like a neat trick, but all its really doing is putting "code behind" up front.

Comment: @A.R.: Have a look at the `GoToStateAction` Mher mentioned, i completely forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

Use data trigger with gotstateaction behavior