# Skipping Storyboards when a control first loads

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard

I have this XAML:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="..." Value="True">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Name="ToTrue">
                ...
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard Name="ToFalse">
                ...
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
    </DataTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
        <SkipStoryboardToFill BeginStoryboardName="ToTrue"/>
        <SkipStoryboardToFill BeginStoryboardName="ToFalse"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

As you can see, I am using `SkipStoryboardToFill` to ensure that when the control first loads it doesn't bother playing the transition storyboards.

This works. However, it spams the console with warnings (since only one of the storyboards will be active) and isn't elegant at all.

Is there a "correct" way of skipping all active storyboards on an element that I'm not seeing?

There is no code-behind to work with here.

Answer (score 1):

Why not implement this as a state transition with `VisualStateManager` rather than data triggers on a style definition

Comment: Because there is no code-behind to trigger the transitions.

Comment: you dont need code-behind to trigger transitions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862332/start-a-visualstate-transition-from-xaml

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use Blend things in my target environment. Ugh, why didn't Microsoft just make all that stuff the standard?

Comment: Well you could create an attached property to do the same :)

Comment: or you could get System.Interactivity from nuget then write your own behaviir (very easy)

Comment: The nuget package is interesting, but I doubt it will be compatibly with [the non-Microsoft runtime](http://www.noesisengine.com/noesis_gui_features.htm) I'm using. I'll look into an attached property though - that might just do the trick. :)

Comment: Turns out you can't add attached props to a ControlTemplate. I hacked around that by accessing the `TemplatedParent` of the template's root control but it seems that my `Loaded` event handler fires too soon - strange, considering that the same event is handled correctly by the EventTrigger. I've spent far too long on this "problem" given that what I have already works...thanks for your efforts though, Dean!